# How to back up a MBR

Tags: backup, mbr

Has anyone tried updating to Windows 10 on a dual boot machine? I'm concerned that Windows 10 might mess with the MBR. 
Is there a way to preserve the MBR and easily restore it if Windows in fact changes it? The other OS on the dual boot is Lubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save your MBR to a file using `dd`

`dd if=/dev/sdX of=~/MBR.backup bs=512 count=1`

Where X is the device you want the backup from. Mind the `if` parameter it is the device (sda) not the partition (sda1,sda2,sdb1, etc...)

Comment: How would I restore it if Windows messes up the MBR? Will restoring it mess up the Windows partition?

Comment: To restore just run `dd if=~/MBR.backup of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1`. Regarding Windows partition, It won't mess it (if you haven't modified it since you `dd`ed your MBR, but I don't know if it will work "out of the box". Anyway, you have a gide in the next link to install windows 10 with linux http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/try-windows-10-youre-running-linux/

Comment: Awesome! The link you posted is great, I'll give it a try soon.